# How to avoid overwrite in query results when a where condition like: "in (23,24,22,23)"

Tags: mysql

I have one such sql:

```
 select name from A where id in (23,24,22,23)
```

When I run it in Navicat, the result only have one result of 23.
 My question is, how to keep the number and order of the query results remains the same as (23,24,22,23).

Comment: **1.** Why do you have `23` repeated? Is it intentional? **2.** If there are records matching, it would come up. Do you have records with IDs `23, 24, 22` - All three?

Comment: Are there rows for 24 22 ? Add order by id

Comment: Yes sir, I repeate the 23 intentional. Because,in my current project, I have one similar requirement.  There are there records in table A , which are :22,23,24.     I want to get four records when I pass the ids 23,24,22,23,  so how to write the sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the order of the result then use `order by` clause like

```
select name from A 
where id in (23,24,22)
order by id;
```

Again, assuming that `id` is a primary key column in your table `A` then there will be only one row with `id = 23`. How do you expect the same row to get repeated automatically unless you make it explicit by using a `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to fetch the records like this, you can use `field` function to get `23,24,22` and order by this sort:

```
select name from A where id in (23,24,22) order by field(id, '23,24,22')
```

then use `union all` get another `23`:

```
(select name from A where id in (23,24,22) order by field(id, '23,24,22'))
union all
select name from A where id = 23
```

Comment: Thanks, It is useful to me.